# ArcObjects custom GP tool: Multiple extensions using IGPFileDomain

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap

I am using IGPFileDomain to make the user select between different file extensions, for example .type1, .type2, .type3. These are added using domain.AddType("type1") etc.

The dialog box then lists all these filters. In addition, it also adds the option to use all 3 extensions/filters at the same time. Example:

```
"File (*.type1)"
"File (*.type2)"
"File (*.type3)"
"File (*.type1;*.type2;*.type3;)"
```

Is it possible to tell/force this dialog to use the last option as default ?

- Oyvind